# Edge browser developer tools local override, not visible when I close developer tools

Tags: css, fonts, customization, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

> Though I describe here about `edge-browser`, this occurs even in `chrome-browser`

## Steps to reproduce

- > You might have seen me as a developer,but I like customisation and `fonts`, one such font I got inspired now is [`quicksand`](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Quicksand)
- I downloaded and installed in my PC,
- I took a simple website ,[`wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

### Current look of website

[image]

- Now I go to edge://settings/fonts,(in chrome chrome://settings/fonts)
- And change `sans-serif` font to `Quicksand`

### Current look of website

[image]

- as you can see, the body font has changed, only the heading font is the problem
- I tried to change the `sans`,`standard`,`fixed-width` fonts,but still the heading didn't change
- when I inspected the website ,my guess was right ,it used some custom font in header:
- `font-family: 'Linux Libertine','Georgia','Times',serif;`
  [image]
- I opened that file which I underlined in green color      **...1**
- I set the overrides folder in sources tab to `C:\Users\nepto\OneDrive\Desktop\EdgeOverrides` (as said in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/javascript/overrides))
- now continuing from `step 1`,I add to overrides folder as shown below
  [image]

#### Current structure

[image]

- now I opened that local file
  (`C:\Users\nepto\OneDrive\Desktop\EdgeOverrides\en.wikipedia.org\longurls\load.php%3-fe414f3.php`)
  in notepad
- now pressing `Ctrl + H` I replace all 3 occurrence of `'Linux Libertine','Georgia','Times',serif` with `inherit` *and save it*

#### Current look

[image]

- As shown above I am too happy for change in font for header
- **Even if i reload the font of header is still quicksand**

---

## Problem Starts

- Now i close the developer tools
- Still same `Quicksand` font!
- **But when i reload now(after closing) the changes are gone,it loses `Quicksand` font**
- Being afraid,i opened developer tools ,and the **`Quicksand` font comes back**
- So the font i like(Quick Sand) works only when the developer tools is opened

> Help me to make it work even if developer tools is closed

Comment: please, looking for attention,am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, it's just impossible to make it work when the F12 DevTools is closed.

The server source codes decided how the webpage looks like in the browser. The DevTools is just for testing and debugging, it can't change the server source file. The Override function just overrides the code not changing the server source code. And all the functions in F12 DevTools are only work when F12 is open. That's why it won't work anymore when you close F12 and refresh the page.

Comment: is there any other way,i want to change just font,please

Comment: You can try to check if there's any extension which can change the fonts. Besides, as this is a chromium issue, you can also report your feedback about it on [this site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).